# what this java line do

Tags: java, object

here I want to get the employee data and do some calculation on it, and print it. 
But the use of line `Employee emp = getEmployeeDetails();` is not what i am understanding

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Employee emp = getEmployeeDetails(); //THIS LINE//
    System.out.println("Id : "+emp.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("Name : "+emp.getEmployeeName());
    System.out.println("Salary : "+emp.getSalary());
    System.out.println("Net Salary : "+emp.getNetSalary());
}

public static Employee getEmployeeDetails(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    System.out.println("Enter id:");
    emp.setEmployeeId(scan.nextInt());
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Name:");
    emp.setEmployeeName(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter salary:");
    emp.setSalary(scan.nextDouble());
    //scan.close();
    return emp;
}
```

Comment: What do you understand of it ? And why do you think it's different ? Share Employee class code

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a method called `getEmployeeDetails` which returns an instance of `Employee`.

What this line does is taking the instance returned by the execution of the method and assigns it to a new variable of type Employee called emp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is just a `method call` and it is another way of writing like this:

```java
public static void main(String [] args){
    // Employee emp = getEmployeeDetails(); //THIS LINE//

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    System.out.println("Enter id:");
    emp.setEmployeeId(scan.nextInt());
    scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Name:");
    emp.setEmployeeName(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter salary:");
    emp.setSalary(scan.nextDouble());
    //scan.close();

    System.out.println("Id : "+emp.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("Name : "+emp.getEmployeeName());
    System.out.println("Salary : "+emp.getSalary());
    System.out.println("Net Salary : "+emp.getNetSalary());
}
```